# Creating var in a loop not working Jquery

Tags: javascript

I want to get all images src from class `'.poi-reviews .poi-review'`

however my code is returning only the first image src, always the same first!

what is wrong with my code ? 
here it is :

```
jQuery('.poi-reviews .poi-review').each(function( ) {

        var fotos = jQuery('.poi-reviews .author-photo-canvas img').attr('src');

        var nome = jQuery('.poi-reviews .review-author-name a').text();

        var divImage = "<img id="+nome+" alt="+nome+"  height='150 'width='150' src="+ fotos +">"  ;

        inicio.after(divImage);

});
```

Comment: can you post also html? or create a fiddle

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough! Let me try explain: I'm creating a app inside a ready html page. There are 10 comments in this page displayed in a linear mode. Each comment has picture and a text. My challenge is to get this comments and the picture! So I'm trying to ready all '.poi-reviews .poi-review' (which are the commentaries classes) and catch all the '.poi-reviews .author-photo-canvas img' which are the img classes. I simply want to take these images from the classes and display them again in another format.. sorry for my loong history haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) takes the DOM selection you have made with `$("#selection")` and iterates over it.

The easiest way to approach this is to have a `results` array and to push the images' `src` attributes to it:

**JavaScript**

```
var results = [];
$("div > img").each(function () {      // selects all img under a div tag and loops through
    results.push($(this).attr("src")); // pushes the src attribute of $(this), aka the img,
})                                     // to the results array
$("#results").text(results.join(", "));
// could also console.log() the results;
// I appended to the DOM so you could easily see it on the fiddle
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="results"></p>
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" />
</div>
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/jAfYs/1/)

Comment: Thanks!!! But is there a way to inside the "each" create a div with img and the src?

Comment: Are you after something like this: `$("#selection").append("<img src='" + $(this).attr("src") +"'>")`? It appends the current image to whatever your `#selection` is on each loop.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough! Let me try explain: I'm creating a app inside a ready html page. There are 10 comments in this page displayed in a linear mode. Each comment has picture and a text. My challenge is to get this comments and the picture! So I'm trying to ready all '.poi-reviews .poi-review' (which are the commentaries classes) and catch all the '.poi-reviews .author-photo-canvas img' which are the img classes. I simply want to take these images from the classes and display them again in another format.. sorry for my loong history haha

Comment: @KarlFrascari Well, the `results` array, in my example, will hold all the image source attributes. That should be all you need to put these images on your page elsewhere. However, it may be faster to use `.clone()` inside of your loop so that you don't have to reload the images.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there are more than one element so, the `attr()` call will return the value of only the first element.

You need this:

```
var fotos = jQuery('.poi-reviews .author-photo-canvas img').map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

Now, `fotos` is a an `Array` containing the urls. Do what you want with them.

Comment: Perfect!! Tks for helping! However Now it's displaying all photos more than once. Is there a way to limit this photos, like if already exists such var with same src, do not display?

 'code'   

//this each repeat 10 times
jQuery('.poi-reviews .poi-review').each(function( ) {
  
    var fotos = jQuery('.poi-reviews .author-photo-canvas img').map(function() {
    
    var caminhoFoto = this.src;
    
    var divImage = "<img id="+nome+" alt="+nome+"  height='150 'width='150' src="+ caminhoFoto +">"  ;
    
    MyDiv.after(divImage);
        
   }).get();

Comment: @KarlFrascari Since you're putting the same styles in the loop—`height: 150px;` and `width:150px`—I suggest just using CSS to apply it to all images of classes `.poi-reviews` and `.poi-review`.